# javascript - validate nested key inside an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following JavaScript object.

```
let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manage": "Mark",
    }
  }
}
```

> How can I create a dynamic function which will take this `JS object obj` as
> a first argument, one parent node as the second argument and a child node
> as the third argument.
>
> if the third argument is present as a child node inside the second
> argument, the function should return true. For example.

```
const childNodeExist = (obj, personalDetails, firstName) => {
    //.. since firstName exists in personalDetails should return true
}

const childNodeExist = (obj, employeeDetails, designation) => {
    //.. since designation exists in employeeDetails should return true
}
const childNodeExist = (obj, employeeDetails, salary) => {
    //.. since salary exists in employeeDetails should return false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

```js
let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manage": "Mark",
    }
  }
}

const childNodeExist = (obj, prop, childProp) => {
    return obj[prop]?.hasOwnProperty(childProp) ?? false; 
}
console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'personalDetails', 'firstName'));

console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'employeeDetails', 'designation'));

console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'employeeDetails', 'salary'));
```

**Update:** Alternative way to support in all the browsers:

```js
let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manage": "Mark",
    }
  }
}

const childNodeExist = (obj, prop, childProp) => {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)? obj[prop].hasOwnProperty(childProp) : false; 
}
console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'personalDetails', 'firstName'));

console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'employeeDetails', 'designation'));

console.log(childNodeExist(obj, 'employeeDetails', 'salary'));
```

Comment: Another way is `return Object.keys(obj[prop]).includes(childProp);`

Comment: @Mamun, optional chaining `?` might not work in all the browsers, right? Alternate way?

Comment: @user2281858, added second solution without using the `?.`, please check:)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you require?

```js
const childNodeExist = (obj, parentNode, childNode) => {
    return (obj[parentNode][childNode] ? true : false);
}

let obj = {
  "type": "user",
  "personalDetails": {
    "firstName": "Steven",
    "address": {
      "streetName": "abcd",
      "zipCode": "012345"
    }
  },
  "employeeDetails": {
    "designation": {
      "id": "1234",
      "manage": "Mark",
    }
  }
}

console.log(childNodeExist(obj, "personalDetails", "firstName"));
console.log(childNodeExist(obj, "employeeDetails", "designation"));
console.log(childNodeExist(obj, "employeeDetails", "salary"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
  const childNodeExist = (obj, parentNode, childNode) => Boolean(obj[parentNode][childNode])
```